# Identifying duplicate requests fired from back end

Tags: java, cloud

I am facing a use case where I need to track down duplicate requests, which are fired through REST API calls from back end. Each request writes into the database, and hence the duplicate requests need not be processed again.

The duplicate requests may come in different threads under the same VM, or may be under different VM's altogether.The problem is how do I identify these duplicate requests ?

Approaches that I can think of :

1. Check in the database every time before processing an incoming request if the outcome of request is already what it is even if we process the request. If yes, then ignore the request else process it.
2. For every incoming request that has been processed, store it in a serialized format in a db mapped to a value (something like the hash index). Then, for every incoming request check if the db already has that request. If yes, then ignore else process it.

But both require db read operations.  Can I do better ?

Comment: It depends a lot on your system. However, why is it even possible that you would create duplicate requests? That's something you should try to solve on the calling end before making the server responsible for distinguishing them. What do those requests do, and why would 2 different threads send the same request?

Comment: Ideally, there should be no duplicate requests. But many times, the users of the system may click on the same button twice or may be the APIs that we have exposed to other teams be called twice. I want to know how can we secure it from my end.

These  requests write into a table in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid DB operations in this case.

Your first approach is very project-specific one.
The second approach also cannot be applied to any code, because there might be cases when users send several equal requests and they both have to be processed.

A more general approach would be for the server to issue tokens, which are then passed with every request by the client to the server. The server in processing every request checks if the token which was passed in the request has already been used by someone. If not, mark in the DB that this token has been used and process the request. Otherwise ignore the request or send an error.
A client can obtain such a token by querying a server method (in this case there is no need to check any tokens for this particular request), or optionally the server can send a new token each time it responds a query.

You should also make sure to clean up outdated tokens once in a while to avoid polluting the database and collisions when generating new ones, if you generate tokens randomly. (See [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Comment: wouldn't the birthday paradox be solved if we just use a GUID - the probability just becomes ~0 for collisions?

Answer (score 0):

The "double submit" is a common problem with web development. With standard forms a common idiom is `submit-redirect-get` which avoids a lot of problems.

I assume you're using javascript to fire requests to a REST backend? A simple approach to prevent one user from duplicating a request is to use javascript to disable the button for a small period of time after it's clicked.

However if you have to prevent this for multiple users, it is highly dependent on your model and other project details.